# how can i upgrade it to react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following v5 code:

```
</Switch>
  ...
  <Route path="/home">
    <Header />
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

[image: v5 code]

Hello how can I upgrade it to v6 ?

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
<Route exact path="/home" element={((<Home />), (<Header />))}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`element={((<Home />), (<Header />))}>` is actually a [Comma Operator expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which when evaluated returns the value of the last operand, `<Header />` in your case.

## Solution

To convert the `react-router-dom@5` code

```
</Switch>
  ...
  <Route path="/home">
    <Header />
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

to `react-router-dom@6` API/syntax, replace the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component with the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes) component and move the routed content onto the `Route` component's `element` prop:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route
    path="/home"
    element={(
      <>
        <Header />
        <Home />
      </>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```

If rendering the header component with several routes it is common to create [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) that render common UI and an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their element into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  ... routes w/o Header
  <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    ... other routes to render with Header
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your package to v6 you need to first uninstall **react-router-dom** package & then try to install using the below command-

```js
npm install react-router-dom@6
```